# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' in recursion with memoization lru_cache

Tags: python, recursion, memoization

Below is the code for fibonacci with lru cache

```
from functools import lru_cache
@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def fib_rec(n):    
    # Base Case
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return n    
    # Recursion
    else:
        return fib_rec(n-1) + fib_rec(n-2)
fib_rec(100)
```

When i tried similar approach for find the target sum with lru cache I got error unhashable list

```
from functools import lru_cache
@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def countWays(elements, target):
    if target < 0:
        return 0
    if target == 0:
        return 1
    total = 0
    for index, element in enumerate(elements):
       total += countWays(elements[index:], target - element) 
    return total
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(countWays([1, 2, 3], 5))
```

If i comment first two lines my code is working, but need to implement lru_cache

Comment: The error seems pretty-self explanatory: `list` is unhashable. Use a tuple: `print(countWays((1, 2, 3), 5))`. If this doesn't make sense, keep in mind `lru_cache` uses the parameter values to determine which calls have already been computed and retrieve the results, and those parameters need to be hashable. `lists` are mutable and therefore unhashable, but since tuples are immutable and hashable, they work.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your `elements` parameter is a mutable type (it's a `List`).

If you use a `Tuple` which is an immutable `Sequence`, the code will work:

```py
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def countWays(elements, target):
  if target < 0:
    return 0
  if target == 0:
    return 1
  total = 0
  for index, element in enumerate(elements):
    total += countWays(elements[index:], target - element) 
  return total

if __name__ == '__main__':
  print(countWays((1, 2, 3), 5)) # Here I changed 1, 2, 3 from a list to a tuple.
```